# Simple stack example, how to return if stack is empty?

Tags: swift

Like many I am learning the new Swift language from Apple, going through the tutorials I came across an example which creates a generic stack. Here is the pop function from that example ...

```
mutating func pop() -> T {
        return elements.removeLast()
}
```

I decided to extend this implementation to not pop when the elements array is empty, but being new to Swift I am unsure what to return if the stack is empty.

```
mutating func pop() -> T {
    if !elements.isEmpty {
        return elements.removeLast()
    } else {
        // return nothing?
}
```

My question is what is the best way to do this in Swift

Comment: I assume removeLast will give you `nil` if the stack is empty and that's exactly what you should be returning when the stack is empty, so there's no need for the if-else statement.

Comment: @LordZsolt: Actually, I think using `removeLast` when the array is empty is a runtime error. In Swift, a type (`T`in this case) cannot be set to `nil`. Only type "optional T" (`T?`) can contain `nil`. If this code compiles, `removeLast` must return `T` and not `T?`, since `T?` cannot be implicitly converted to `T` in this way.

Comment: @AlvinThompson Sorry, haven't spent enough time with Swift... I've got exams...

Comment: @LordZsolt: I have to admit, Swift seems to be a well designed language. We'll see if that assessment holds over time, though.  :)

Comment: @AlvinThompson I might get flagged for off-topic commenting, but I've read a few (50-100) pages from the Swift book, and I kinda like it as well. Though the Haskell-style return syntax gives me the creeps, since I associate it with Clean (another functional programming language like Haskell, but other person on the planet uses it besides our teacher), which was the source of A LOT of frustration for me.

Comment: @LordZsolt: I actually love the fact that you can return multiple values. Depending on how it's implemented, it can make things far more efficient. For example, suppose you need a function which returns the location of something in "x" and "y" coordinates. In Java and other languages, you would have to create a new object (normally on the heap) to hold the values. If this were a game and you needed to call this function zillions of times, creating all those temporary objects would be very inefficient. I'm assuming the Swift places the return values on the call stack.

Comment: For this reason, I actually suggested that Java be amended to allow multiple return values when it was still the new kid on the block, but they rejected it on the grounds that it would make the language "less object oriented". I'm sure they regretted that decision shortly after it became clear what a performance bottleneck such a common use case was, and they had to dedicate the next 3 releases dedicated to making the garbage collector more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the type of thing that optionals are for. Optionals are like regular variables, except they have a special case to say, "no value is assigned", so instead of returning type "T", return type "optional T":

```
mutating func pop() -> T? {
    if !elements.isEmpty {
        return elements.removeLast() // return the last item on the stack
    } else {
        return nil // indicate there was nothing on the stack
    }
}
```

Of course, when using this function you'll have to check if you got an actual value or not. You can do that with an "if" statement or the "if let" construct. If you have an optional in a var called `optionalItem`, you can use something like `if optionalItem { ... }`. Only if `optionalItem` has a value is the code in the `if` block executed.

The "if let" construct goes a step further by retrieving the item from the optional for you. Do something like:

```
if let item = myStack.pop() { // this implicitly unwraps the optional if present
    // Do something. "item" is of type T, not T?
else {
    // Nothing was on the stack. "item" is not defined
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alvin much appreciated, I am just finishing the first video (402) and I see that optionals are at the start of the next one (403) :) Thanks again for taking the time to put me on the right track.

Comment: No problem. Optionals are a very nice way of handling the "no value" case once you get the hang of them. I have to admit, it took me a bit to fully adjust to the concept since I'm used to just using "null" in Java and C++. But now that I have, I think they're great. They express intent in both the function and client much more clearly, and they truly are safer.

Answer (score 1):

```
func pop() -> T? {
    if !elements.isEmpty {
        return elements.removeLast()
    } else {
        // return nothing?
        return nil
}
}
```